# Disable month selection in jQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, datepicker

How can I remove the buttons to select the past or next month in jQuery datepicker?

I found the same question on SO, but it did not work for me.

I tried this, but without success:

```
$("#date").datepicker({
  changeMonth: false,
  changeYear: false,
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  duration: 'fast'
}).focus(function() {
  $(".ui-datepicker-prev, .ui-datepicker-next").remove();
});​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code did the trick :)

```
$('#datepicker').find('.ui-datepicker-next').remove();
$('#datepicker').find('.ui-datepicker-prev').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you'll need to do minDate and maxDate to do this. The changeMonth option just sets whether changing the month is allowed within a dropdown or not.

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/